# Test Android Navigation starting from arbitrary location

Tags: java, android, testing, android-testing, android-navigation

I have the following navgraph with `startDestination` as `card_list`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/card_list">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/card_list"
        android:name="bbct.android.common.fragment.BaseballCardList"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/card_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_details"
            app:destination="@id/card_details" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/card_details"
        android:name="bbct.android.common.fragment.BaseballCardDetails"
        android:label="@string/card_details_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/card_details">
        <argument
            android:name="id"
            app:argType="long" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Now I want to write a test starting at `card_details`:

```
public class NavigationTest {
    @Test
    public void clickOnSaveNavigatesFromDetailsBackToList() {
        TestNavHostController navController = new TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext());
        FragmentScenario<BaseballCardDetails> listScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(
            BaseballCardDetails.class,
            null,
            R.style.AppTheme
        );
        listScenario.onFragment(fragment -> {
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph);
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController);
        });
        assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentDestination()).getId())
            .isEqualTo(R.id.card_details);
        BaseballCard card = new BaseballCard(
            true,
            "Mint",
            "Code Guru Apps",
            1993,
            "1",
            50000,
            1,
            "Code Guru",
            "Code Guru Devs",
            "Catcher"
        );
        BBCTTestUtil.sendKeysToCardDetails(card);
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.save_button)).perform(ViewActions.click());
        assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentDestination()).getId())
            .isEqualTo(R.id.card_list);
    }
}
```

This fails on

```
        assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentDestination()).getId())
            .isEqualTo(R.id.card_details);
```

because the `TestNavHostController` is on the `startDestination` of `card_list`.

The actual failure message is

> expected: 2131296377
>
> but was : 2131296378
>
> at bbct.android.common.navigation.NavigationTest.clickOnSaveNavigatesFromDetailsBackToList(NavigationTest.java:116)

- `2131296377` is the id for `card_list`
- `2131296378` is the id for `card_details`
- Line 116 is the previously mentioned `assertThat()`

How do I force this test to start from the correct destination? Or is this not the correct way to write such a test? Am I supposed to write such a test by navigating to `card_details` first by performing the UI operations that a user would normally do?

---

Dependencies:

In case it matters, I have the following nav dependency versions:

```
    navVersion = '2.4.2'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$navVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$navVersion"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Testing Navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing):

> Just like a real `NavController`, you must call `setGraph` to initialize the `TestNavHostController`. In this example, the fragment being tested was the start destination of our graph. **`TestNavHostController` provides a [`setCurrentDestination`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/testing/TestNavHostController#setCurrentDestination(kotlin.Int,android.os.Bundle)) method that allows you to set the current destination (and optionally, arguments for that destination) so that the `NavController` is in the correct state before your test begins.**

So add a call to `setCurrentDestination` to initialize your test on a particular destination:

```
listScenario.onFragment(fragment -> {
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph);

    // Create arguments using Safe Args generated classes
    // or construct the Bundle directly
    BaseballCardDetailsArgs args = new BaseballCardDetailsArgs.Builder(0).build();
    Bundle arguments = args.toBundle();

    // Then set the current destination to your card_details
    navController.setCurrentDestination(R.id.card_details, arguments);

    Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController);
});
```

Comment: This appears to be the right idea. However, `Bundle arguments = new BaseballCardDetailsArgs(0);` gives an error "Expected 0 arguments found 1". Removing the `0` gives "Required type: Bundle. Provided: BaseballCardDetailsArgs" for obvious reasons. I will look more into the correct way to create a bundle using safe args and post a new question if necessary.

Comment: Side note, removing arguments entirely gives me a NPE. In theory, the argument is optional here. When given an `id`, the `BaseballCardDetails` fragment allows the user to edit an existing card. If no `id` is given, then this fragment will create a new card. I think the current implementation takes a Bundle with no id or an id with some invalid value (like -1). It would be nice to be able to handle a `null` bundle, too, or instead. But that's another issue and possibly a new SO question.

Comment: Your argument has no default value, so it definitely is a required value. I had forgotten the `toBundle()` call, which is how you get a Bundle from the generated Args class.

Comment: p.s. Back at my desktop and I see I already tried `setCurrentDestination()`, but put it after `setViewNavController()`. I guess the order matters here.

Comment: Also, after doing `Bundle arguments = new BaseballCardDetailsArgs(0).toBundle();` Android Studio shows red squiggly under `(0)` and says "Expected 0 arguments but found 1". Strangely compiling gives a different error: "error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to HashMap"

Comment: What's the correct way to call the BaseballCardDetailsArgs constructor? Or how do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I guess I could create a `HashMap` and add an `"id"` to it, but then I might as well create the `Bundle` directly and not bother with safeargs at all.

Comment: What Safe Args plugin are you using? `'androidx.navigation.safeargs'` or `'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'`? They generate different code.

Comment: `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"`. FWIW, this is a Java app. I haven't yet converted it to Kotlin.

Comment: Ah, the Java generated code uses a `Builder` pattern for constructing the Args object. I've updated the code to show how that works.

Comment: Thanks. Might be useful for future visitors to include both variations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This essentially answers my original question about starting a test at a specific destination. Unfortunately, it doesn't get me to a passing test yet, but I think I need to post a new question now.

Comment: If you have some time to look at it, my new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456277/passing-arguments-to-a-destination-in-a-test