# Passing arguments to a destination in a test

Tags: java, android, testing, android-testing, android-architecture-navigation

In my Android app, I have the following navgraph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/card_list">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/card_list"
        android:name="bbct.android.common.fragment.BaseballCardList"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/card_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_details"
            app:destination="@id/card_details" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/card_details"
        android:name="bbct.android.common.fragment.BaseballCardDetails"
        android:label="@string/card_details_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/card_details">
        <argument
            android:name="id"
            app:argType="long" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

As you can see `card_details` takes an `id` argument. If this is `-1`, then the detail view is opened with all blank fields and allows the user to create a new card. If `id` is a positive value, it is used to fetch a row from the database and populates the form for editing.

Now I am writing a test to verify that while editing a card that the app navigates back to `card_list` when the user clicks the save button:

```
public class NavigationTest {
    @Test
    public void clickOnSaveNavigatesFromDetailsBackToList() {
        TestNavHostController navController = new TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext());
        FragmentScenario<BaseballCardDetails> detailsScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(
            BaseballCardDetails.class,
            null,
            R.style.AppTheme
        );
        detailsScenario.onFragment(fragment -> {
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph);
            BaseballCardDetailsArgs args = new BaseballCardDetailsArgs.Builder(0).build();
            navController.setCurrentDestination(R.id.card_details, args.toBundle());
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController);
        });
        assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentDestination()).getId())
            .isEqualTo(R.id.card_details);
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.save_button)).perform(ViewActions.click());
        assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentDestination()).getId())
            .isEqualTo(R.id.card_list);
    }
}
```

However, when this test navigates to `card_details`, the form fields are not populated by the card's values. To see what is going on, I added `Log.d()` calls to my app:

```
public class BaseballCardDetails extends Fragment {
    // ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

        populateTextEdits();
    }

    private void populateTextEdits() {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        Log.d(TAG, "args: " + args);

        // ...
    }
}
```

This outputs

> 05-31 21:35:13.589 29002 29002 D bbct.android.common.fragment.BaseballCardDetails: args: null

As you can see `args` is `null`. Why isn't the arguments from my test being passed through to the fragment here? More importantly, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
FragmentScenario<BaseballCardDetails> detailsScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(
        BaseballCardDetails.class,
        null,
        R.style.AppTheme
    );
```

That `null` are the arguments passed to your fragment. Hence, `getArguments()` is null because the arguments you've passed to your fragment is null. Since the NavController isn't creating your fragment in your test (instead, it is `launchInContainer` that is creating it), the arguments you set via `setCurrentDestination` only apply to the `NavBackEntry`'s arguments (i.e., if you call `navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry().getArguments()`).

Instead of passing `null` to `launchInContainer`, you'll want to move the construction of your `args` Bundle to before your call to `launchInContainer`:

```
@Test
public void clickOnSaveNavigatesFromDetailsBackToList() {
    TestNavHostController navController = new TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext());

    // Move args construction here
    BaseballCardDetailsArgs args = new BaseballCardDetailsArgs.Builder(0).build();
    Bundle bundleArgs = args.toBundle();

    // And pass the bundleArgs into launchInContainer:
    FragmentScenario<BaseballCardDetails> detailsScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(
        BaseballCardDetails.class,
        bundleArgs,
        R.style.AppTheme
    );
    detailsScenario.onFragment(fragment -> {
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph);

        // Reuse the same bundleArgs here as well
        navController.setCurrentDestination(R.id.card_details, bundleArgs);
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController);
    });
    assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentDestination()).getId())
        .isEqualTo(R.id.card_details);
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.save_button)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentDestination()).getId())
        .isEqualTo(R.id.card_list);
}
```